# automorphism of finitly generated group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let G be a finitely generated group , then can we say that the group of  automorphisms of G is also finitely generated .If yes what is the relation between the number of generators.If not under what condition the group of  automorphism is finitely generated

Comment: It need not be finitely generated. Any countable group is the outer automorphism group of a fg group.

Comment: @Benjamin: Do you have a reference for this interesting fact?

Comment: unfortunately i have no reference. if instead of group of automorphism if we take group of central automorphisms then can we say that above result is true

Comment: Inna Bumagin and Daniel Wise proved it. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404904003111

Comment: The Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(2,4)$ has an infinitely generated automorphism group (D.J. Collins, F. Levin, Automorphisms and hopﬁcity of certain Baumslag-Solitar groups,
Arch. Math. 40 (1983), 385–400.)